# Using JSON API Serializer to create more complicated JSON

Tags: node.js, json, api-design, json-api, jsonapi-serialize

The examples [here](https://github.com/SeyZ/jsonapi-serializer) don't go nearly far enough in explaining how to produce a more complicated structure...

If I want to end up with something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "mobile_screens",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Watch"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "mobile_screen_components": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1_1",
            "type": "mobile_screen_components"
          },
          {
            "id": "1_2",
            "type": "mobile_screen_components"
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "1_1",
      "type": "mobile_screen_components",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Featured Playlist",
        "display_type": "shelf"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "playlist": {
          "data": {
            "id": "938973798001",
            "type": "playlists"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "938973798001",
      "type": "playlists",
      "relationships": {
        "videos": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "5536725488001",
              "type": "videos"
            },
            {
              "id": "5535943875001",
              "type": "videos"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5536725488001",
      "type": "videos",
      "attributes": {
        "duration": 78321,
        "live_stream": false,
        "thumbnail": {
          "width": 1280,
          "url":
            "http://xxx.jpg?pubId=694940094001",
          "height": 720
        },
        "last_published_date": "2017-08-09T18:26:04.899Z",
        "streams": [
          {
            "url":
              "http://xxx.m3u8",
            "mime_type": "MP4"
          }
        ],
        "last_modified_date": "2017-08-09T18:26:27.621Z",
        "description": "xxx",
        "fn__media_tags": [
          "weather",
          "personality"
        ],
        "created_date": "2017-08-09T18:23:16.830Z",
        "title": "NOAA predicts most active hurricane season since 2010",
        "fn__tve_authentication_required": false
      }
    },
    ...,
  ]
}
```

what is the most simple data structure and serializer I can set up?

I get stumped after something like:

```
const mobile_screen_components = responses.map((currentValue, index) => {
  id[`id_${index}`];
});
const dataSet = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Watch',
  mobile_screen_components,
};
const ScreenSerializer = new JSONAPISerializer('mobile_screens', {
  attributes: ['title', 'mobile_screen_components'],
  mobile_screen_components: {
    ref: 'id',
  }
});
```

Which only gives me:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "mobile_screens",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": { "title": "Watch" },
    "relationships": {
      "mobile-screen-components": {
        "data": [
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_0" },
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_1" },
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_2" },
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_3" },
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_4" },
          { "type": "mobile_screen_components", "id": "1_5" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to get the "included" sibling to "data." etc.

Comment: I think you should boil down your question as much as you can.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kamran cut out some more of that initial JSON structure, but that's about as minimal of a representation as I can make...

Comment: Although it wasn't immediately clear, this question is based on using https://github.com/SeyZ/jsonapi-serializer with the intent of building APIs using http://jsonapi.org/ spec.

Comment: Sorry I don't get how is your initial data?, would you specify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the question is:

> what is the most simple data structure and serializer I can set up?

Below is the simplest object that can be converted to JSON similar to JSON in the question using `jsonapi-serializer`:

```
let dataSet = {
  id: '1',
  title: 'Watch',
  mobile_screen_components: [
    {
      id: '1_1',
      title: 'Featured Playlists',
      display_type: 'shelf',
      playlists: {
        id: 938973798001,
        videos: [
          {
            id: 5536725488001,
            duration: 78321,
            live_stream: false
          },
          {
            id: 5535943875001,
            duration: 52621,
            live_stream: true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

To serialize this object to JSON API, I used the following code:

```
let json = new JSONAPISerializer('mobile_screen', {
  attributes: ['id', 'title', 'mobile_screen_components'],
  mobile_screen_components: {
    ref: 'id',
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'display_type', 'playlists'],
    playlists: {
      ref: 'id',
      attributes: ['id', 'videos'],
      videos: {
        ref: 'id',
        attributes: ['id', 'duration', 'live_stream']
      }
    }
  }
}).serialize(dataSet);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
```

1. The first parameter of `JSONAPISerializer` constructor is the resource type.
2. The second parameter is the serialization options.
3. Each level of the options equals to the level of the nested object in serialized object.
4. `ref` - if present, it's considered as a relationships.
5. `attributes` - an array of attributes to show.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

First of all we have to understand the **[JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/#introduction)**  [`document data structure`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure)

**[0.1]** Refering to the top level (object root keys) :

> A document **MUST** contain at least one of the following top-level
>   members:
>
> ```
> data: the document’s “primary data” 
> errors: an array of error objects   
> meta: a meta object that contains non-standard meta-information.
> ```
>
> A document **MAY** contain any of these top-level members:
>
> ```
> jsonapi: an object describing the server’s implementation
> links: a links object related to the primary data.
> included: an array of resource objects that are related to the primary data and/or each other (“included resources”).
> ```

**[0.2]**

> The document’s “primary data” is a representation of the resource **or**
>   collection of resources targeted by a request.
>
> Primary data **MUST** be either:
>
> 1. a single resource identifier object, or
>      null, for requests that target single resources
> 2. an array of resource identifier
>      objects, or an empty array ([]), for reqs. that target
>      collections

---

## Example

The following primary data is a single resource object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      // ... this article's attributes
    },
    "relationships": {
      // ... this article's relationships
    }
  }
}
```

In the (`jsonapi-serializer`) documentation : [Available serialization option (opts argument)](https://github.com/SeyZ/jsonapi-serializer#available-serialization-option-opts-argument)

So in order to add the `included` (*top-level member*) I performed the following test :

```
var JsonApiSerializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Serializer;
const DATASET = {
  id:23,title:'Lifestyle',slug:'lifestyle',
  subcategories: [
   {description:'Practices for becoming 31337.',id:1337,title:'Elite'},
   {description:'Practices for health.',id:69,title:'Vitality'}
  ]
}
const TEMPLATE = {
  topLevelLinks:{self:'http://example.com'},
  dataLinks:{self:function(collection){return 'http://example.com/'+collection.id}},
  attributes:['title','slug','subcategories'],
  subcategories:{ref:'id',attributes:['id','title','description']}
}
let SERIALIZER = new JsonApiSerializer('pratices', DATASET, TEMPLATE)
console.log(SERIALIZER)
```

With the following output :

```
{ links: { self: 'http://example.com' },
  included: 
   [ { type: 'subcategories', id: '1337', attributes: [Object] },
     { type: 'subcategories', id: '69', attributes: [Object] } ],
  data: 
   { type: 'pratices',
     id: '23',
     links: { self: 'http://example.com/23' },
     attributes: { title: 'Lifestyle', slug: 'lifestyle' },
     relationships: { subcategories: [Object] } } }
```

As you may observe, the `included` is correctly populated.

---

**NOTE : If you need more help with your `dataSet`, edit your question with the original data.**

Comment: That long bit of JSON (my first quoted "code") represents the data. Or at least how it needs to be output.

Comment: @two7s_clash : you need to create a `TEMPLATE` that fits your data structure, we cannot really do that for you, since you haven't showed original data, just an output. The template for the parser is built based upon your original data to obtain the output you really want

Comment: the output data is the same as the input data, the former is just serialized in a specific way. As you can see from the above answers, my very question is about how to format the data as input to give me the form I want as output. totally doable.